# How to create an infinite card slider?

Tags: javascript, html, carousel

I created a card slider but if there is no card at the end it stop and clicking on the next button it starts from the beginning. I want to make it an infinite slider so that the first card is appended to the last one Please help me do that. I tried adding more javascript code but it didn't work.

```
<section class="wow fadeInUp">
    <div id="cCarousel">
      <div class="arrow" id="prev"><i class="fa-solid fa-chevron-left"></i></div>
      <div class="arrow" id="next"><i class="fa-solid fa-chevron-right"></i></div>
  
      <div id="carousel-vp">
        <div id="cCarousel-inner">
  
            <div id="chhatak-div" class="service-item p-4 cCarousel-item">
                <div class="overflow-hidden mb-4">
                    <img id="chhatak-img" class="img-fluid" src="https://slp-statics.astockcdn.net/static_assets/staging/22spring/free/browse-vector-categories-collections/Card4_399895799.jpg?width=580" alt="">
                </div>
                
                <!-- <p>Stet stet justo dolor sed duo. Ut clita sea sit ipsum diam lorem diam.</p> -->
                <a id="chhatak" class="btn-slide mt-2" href="projects.html"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i><span>View</span></a>
            </div>

            <div id="shahjibazarpower-div" class="service-item p-4 cCarousel-item">
                <div class="overflow-hidden mb-4">
                    <img id="shahjibazarpower-img" class="img-fluid" src="https://slp-statics.astockcdn.net/static_assets/staging/22spring/free/browse-vector-categories-collections/Card4_399895799.jpg?width=580" alt="">
                </div>
                
                <!-- <p>Stet stet justo dolor sed duo. Ut clita sea sit ipsum diam lorem diam.</p> -->
                <a id="shahjibazarpower" class="btn-slide mt-2" href="projects.html"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i><span>View</span></a>
            </div>

            <div id="water1-div" class="service-item p-4 cCarousel-item">
                <div class="overflow-hidden mb-4">
                    <img id="water1-img" class="img-fluid" src="https://slp-statics.astockcdn.net/static_assets/staging/22spring/free/browse-vector-categories-collections/Card4_399895799.jpg?width=580" alt="">
                </div>
                
                <!-- <p>Stet stet justo dolor sed duo. Ut clita sea sit ipsum diam lorem diam.</p> -->
                <a id="water1" class="btn-slide mt-2" href="projects.html"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i><span>View</span></a>
            </div>

            <div id="modhumotipower-div" class="service-item p-4 cCarousel-item">
                <div class="overflow-hidden mb-4">
                    <img id="modhumotipower-img" class="img-fluid" src="https://slp-statics.astockcdn.net/static_assets/staging/22spring/free/browse-vector-categories-collections/Card4_399895799.jpg?width=580" alt="">
                </div>
                
                <!-- <p>Stet stet justo dolor sed duo. Ut clita sea sit ipsum diam lorem diam.</p> -->
                <a id="modhumotipower" class="btn-slide mt-2" href="projects.html"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i><span>View</span></a>
            </div>

            <div id="goroshalpower-div" class="service-item p-4 cCarousel-item">
                <div class="overflow-hidden mb-4">
                    <img id="goroshalpower-img" class="img-fluid" src="https://slp-statics.astockcdn.net/static_assets/staging/22spring/free/browse-vector-categories-collections/Card4_399895799.jpg?width=580" alt="">
                </div>
                
                <!-- <p>Stet stet justo dolor sed duo. Ut clita sea sit ipsum diam lorem diam.</p> -->
                <a id="goroshalpower" class="btn-slide mt-2" href="projects.html"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i><span>View</span></a>
            </div>

            <div id="barisalpower-div" class="service-item p-4 cCarousel-item">
                <div class="overflow-hidden mb-4">
                    <img id="barisalpower-img" class="img-fluid" src="https://slp-statics.astockcdn.net/static_assets/staging/22spring/free/browse-vector-categories-collections/Card4_399895799.jpg?width=580" alt="">
                </div>
                
                <!-- <p>Stet stet justo dolor sed duo. Ut clita sea sit ipsum diam lorem diam.</p> -->
                <a id="barisalpower" class="btn-slide mt-2" href="projects.html"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i><span>View</span></a>
            </div>

     
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

javascript:

```
let oldViewportWidth = window.innerWidth;
    let slideIndex = 0;
    let isHovered = false; // Variable to track hover state
    let timerId; // Variable to store the interval timer ID

    function mediaManagement() {
    const newViewportWidth = window.innerWidth;

    if (leftValue <= -totalMovementSize && oldViewportWidth < newViewportWidth) {
        leftValue += totalMovementSize;
        cCarouselInner.style.left = leftValue + "px";
        oldViewportWidth = newViewportWidth;
    } else if (
        leftValue <= -totalMovementSize &&
        oldViewportWidth > newViewportWidth
    ) {
        leftValue -= totalMovementSize;
        cCarouselInner.style.left = leftValue + "px";
        oldViewportWidth = newViewportWidth;
    }
    }

    function next1() {
    if (!isHovered) {
        slideIndex++;
        if (slideIndex >= cCarouselInner.children.length) {
        slideIndex = 0;
        }
        cCarouselInner.style.left = -slideIndex * totalMovementSize + "px";
    }
    }

    function prev1() {
    if (!isHovered) {
        slideIndex--;
        if (slideIndex < 0) {
        slideIndex = cCarouselInner.children.length - 1;
        }
        cCarouselInner.style.left = -slideIndex * totalMovementSize + "px";
    }
    }

    function startSlideshow() {
        timerId = setInterval(next1, 4000);
    }

    function stopSlideshow() {
    clearInterval(timerId);
    }

    // Add event listeners for hover events
    cCarouselInner.addEventListener("mouseenter", function () {
        isHovered = true;
        stopSlideshow();
    });

    cCarouselInner.addEventListener("mouseleave", function () {
        isHovered = false;
        startSlideshow();
    });

    // Add event listeners for next and previous buttons
    const prevButton = document.getElementById("prev");
    const nextButton = document.getElementById("next");

    prevButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
        prev1();
        stopSlideshow();
    });

    nextButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
        next1();
        stopSlideshow();
    });

    // Start the slideshow initially
    startSlideshow();
```

css:

```
    #cCarousel {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 1250px;
  margin: auto;
}

#cCarousel .arrow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  display: flex;
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 26px;
  color: white;
  background: #00000072;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#cCarousel #prev {
  left: 0px;
}

#cCarousel #next {
  right: 0px;
}

#carousel-vp {
  width: 1120px;
  height: 500px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: auto;
}


@media (max-width: 1262px) {
    #cCarousel{
        width: 900px;
    }

    #carousel-vp {
      width: 840px;
    }

  }


@media (max-width: 974px) {
    #cCarousel{
        width: 100%;
    }

    #carousel-vp {
        width: 560px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  #carousel-vp {
    width: 270px;
  }
}

#cCarousel #cCarousel-inner {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
  gap: 10px;
  left: 0px;
}

.cCarousel-item {
  width: 270px;
  height: 460px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  padding: 0 !important;
  border-radius: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: without going in your code, I would say 2 things. First if you have your full carousel, when you arrive at the end, you can "rewind" it to the first place. Second if you want to "append", build your carousel with only 3 images, current, previous, next... Your full carousel is with display none. You keep same logic for your index, except each time you copy img from hidden carousel to the 3.